# Memory Leak While Getting Frames of Video with EmguCV, .NET

Tags: c#, .net, memory-leaks, emgucv

Hi I am trying to write a function to extract all frames from a video using EmguCV in .NET. I do this by using the Emgu Capture class to QueryFrame() the video until that function returns null. I need to save these captured frames to the disk during the process. But I must have a memory leak somewhere because medium sized videos yield a System.OutOfMemoryException

The code is here:

```
private void GetFramesFromVideo(string filename)
{
    Capture capture = new Capture(filename);
    bool capturing = true; //loop condition
    int count = 0;

    while (capturing) {
        Mat mat = capture.QueryFrame();//take frame from video

        if (mat != null) //save to disk if not null
        {
            string savePath = Globals.TempFolderPath +
                String.Format("temp-video-frame{0:000000}.jpg", count++); ; 


            Bitmap frame = mat.ToImage<Bgr, Byte>().ToBitmap(); //EXCEPTION THROWN HERE
            frame.Save(savePath, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);  
            frame.Dispose();
            mat.Dispose();

        }
        else //eof
        {
            capturing = false;
        }

    }

    ShowDebugMessage(String.Format("Extracted {0} images from video", count));

}
```

This function works, it does get all the frames from the video. I just can't understand what the problem is with memory. The line `Bitmap frame = mat.ToImage<Bgr, Byte>().ToBitmap();` is what throws the exception so I tried disposing the two things used in that line, but that didn't solve the issue. Note that I am using EmguCV 3.0.1 because of stupid reasons that prevent updating.

Comment: Why aren't you using simply `mat.Save(savePath)`? Would spare you to put the frame in memory as a Bitmap... (not an expert of EmguCV, just suggesting by reading the documentation)

Comment: I had it that way previously, but the resulting jpgs were low quality and I didn't see how to change the compression. Using it to save as bitmaps was fine, but took a lot of disk space. Although using the mat.Save() function didn't give me a memory leak.

Comment: Can you save to png? It's usually less lossy than jpg.

Comment: I've noticed that `mat.ToImage<Bgr, Byte>()` returns `TImage` that is disposable as well, so either to dispose it as well, or better use `using (...) {...}`. BTW have you checked via profiler like WinDbg/Deleaker/DotMemory/etc.?